# How to better personalize angular-bootstrap-calendar?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to use angular-bootstrap-calendar and create a calendar where a user can select multiple dates in one go and add an event to the selected range. So far, following the documentation, I can create a custom template for a monthly cell or allow a user to select a range of dates. Unfortunately, as soon as I try to mix the two things I cannot select the range anymore but the custom template is working fine. I have created the calendar in this way

```
<mwl-calendar
    view="calendarView"
    view-date="viewDate"
    events="prices"
    view-title="calendarTitle"
    on-event-click="eventClicked(calendarEvent)"
    on-event-times-changed="calendarEvent.startsAt = calendarNewEventStart; calendarEvent.endsAt = calendarNewEventEnd"
    custom-template-urls="{calendarMonthCell: 'customMonthCell.html'}"
    on-date-range-select="rangeSelected(calendarRangeStartDate, calendarRangeEndDate)"
    cell-is-open="true"
    cell-modifier="cellModifier(calendarCell)">
</mwl-calendar>
```

Can anyone show me a plunker working example please?

[Plunker to the example http://plnkr.co/edit/VHkbUEkrOcmnhiPOPbc4](http://plnkr.co/edit/VHkbUEkrOcmnhiPOPbc4)

Comment: I am not able to create custom template also by using above code.The script tag is not working.